# Conventions for storing Visual C# projects in an SVN repo

Tags: c#, svn, version-control, project

Basically my question is **what** parts of a C# do you store in a repository? In a class I took last year, I was told that you never store generated files in version control (so if you are writing c, dont store the .o/.exe files).

But it is easy with c, because you just save the .c, .h and makefile, and you can just checkout the repo, run the make file, and everything works.

But with C# projects in Visual Studio I am having some problems deciding what to store.

If I store just the .cs files, it is awkward to add them to the project on other computers. Am I supposed to store the project file too?

The problem I am running into is that I used to just store the whole project directory. But then when I would put the project on a different computer, it would complain that the temporaryKey is wrong (.pfx file)...

So what am I supposed to store?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

They way I do it - I am storing everything except:

- `bin` and `obj` directories of each project in solution
- `.user` and `.suo` files - they contain user-specific project and solution options
- Resharper generated files (the Resharper is an Visual studio extension that creates some files in solution folder)

Basically, rule of thumb is not to store anything that is specific to a particular machine or is generated by a tool (be it a compiler or a Visual Studio extension - like Resharper in my case).

Answer (score 2):

The advice doesn't *quite* fit how one works with most C# projects, in particular the UI - Visual Studio generates the designer files, for example, which one *should* check in (or else, other getting the source will not be able to compile).

In general, do not store items that are the artefacts of compilation - the assemblies that are produced by your code.

Items that are not needed for compilation and running (such as user specific setting files) should not be checked in either.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in agreement with everyone else - ignore binarys, .suo and .user - however I do find that using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) simplifies this considerably as you commit directly from VS and it just works.

Comment: For working within VS using SVN I really can't recommend it enough. It does have a few annoyances (no double click to compare) - but these are incredible minor compared to the major gain of using it.

Comment: @NikolaAnusev I spent a good time trying other options before settling on AnkhSvn. It is amazing..

Comment: I got ankh, and it looks reallly nice! but what do you do with the temporary key files? (.pfx). do you add them to the repo?? ...or is there a way to just not use keys at all (turn off the signing or what ever)

Answer (score 1):

I store the entire solution folder, but I add exceptions for *.user, *.suo files.  I also do not commit any bin and obj folders.

Answer (score 1):

We store everything in the solution folder and its subfolders. But we add these exclusions via

```
`svn:ignore` = 
*.suo
*.ncb
*.user
_ReSharper.*
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Dd]ebug
[Rr]elease
```

For references
[svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html)
[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)

Comment: Mmm, How would I use that statement? svn commit * <your above statement here>?

Comment: In the meantime I have added references to TortoiseSVN and to the SVN Book

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else seems to have covered the majority of this, but I thought I would add my two cents.  I use the following global ignore pattern for C# development.  This covers system files, and unwanted solution files.

*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej .*~ *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store thumbs.db Thumbs.db *.bak *.class *.dll *.exe *.mine *.obj *.ncb *.lib *.log *.idb *.pdb *.ilk *.msi *.res *.pch *.suo *.exp *.*~ *.~* ~*.* cvs CVS .CVS .cvs release Release debug Debug ignore Ignore obj Obj *.csproj.user *.user bin BIN

For more information on global vs. local ignore patterns for svn, look here:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

**General Rule of Thumb**

Never store any generated output or user specific settings.  Also, if possible, avoid storing unnecessary binary files as they cannot use contextual merging.